# Validating Input Value - PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have simple GUI with two inputs and exit button. Inputs have default_value = 0.00. I want to validate user change in the way that input can be only float format,'.2f' and <= 5.0. Example from cookbook helps partially. When I use this code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Input(key='first_input', enable_events=True, default_text='0.00')],
          [sg.Input(key='second_input', enable_events=True, default_text='0.00')],
          [sg.Button('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('Main', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in ['Exit', sg.WIN_CLOSED]:
        break
    if event == 'first_input' and values['first_input']:
        try:
            in_as_float = float(values['first_input'])
            if float(values['first_input']) > 5:
                window['first_input'].update('5')
        except:
            if len(values['first_input']) == 1 and values['first_input'][0] == '-':
                continue
            window['first_input'].update(values['first_input'][:-1])

window.close()
```

But when user delete content of "first_input" and decide to fill "second_input" the previous one remains empty. How to prevent it and for example back to default value when user left input empty.

I have tried to do someting like:

```
if values['first_input'] == '':
   window['firs_input'].update['0.00']
```

but this do not work because it will not let to user delete content. For example when he want to change from 3 to 4. After he delete 3 0.00 apears immediately.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to validate value by regex, maybe you can test it meet all requirements.

```py
import re
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def select(element):
    element.Widget.select_range(0, 'end')
    element.Widget.icursor('end')

def validate(text):
    result = re.match(regex, text)
    return False if result is None or result.group() != text else True

regex = "^[+-]?([0-5](\.(\d{0,2}))?)?$"
old = {'IN1':'0.00', 'IN2':'0.00'}
validate_inputs = ('IN1', 'IN2')

layout = [
    [sg.Input('0.00', enable_events=True, key='IN1')],
    [sg.Input('0.00', enable_events=True, key='IN2')],
    [sg.Button('Exit')],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
select(window['IN1'])
for key in validate_inputs:
    window[key].bind('<FocusIn>',  ' IN')
    window[key].bind('<FocusOut>', ' OUT')

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in ['Exit', sg.WIN_CLOSED]:
        break
    elif event in validate_inputs:
        element, text = window[event], values[event]
        if validate(text):
            try:
                v = float(text)
                if v > 5:
                    element.update(old[event])
                    continue
            except ValueError as e:
                pass
            old[event] = text
        else:
            element.update(old[event])
    elif event.endswith(' IN'):
        key = event.split()[0]
        element, text = window[key], values[key]
        select(element)
    elif event.endswith(' OUT'):
        key = event.split()[0]
        element, text = window[key], values[key]
        try:
            v = float(text)
            element.update(f'{v:.2f}')
        except ValueError as e:
            element.update('0.00')

window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now exactly as I wanted. A lot of interesting line in your code I can learn from. Cheers!